# I am trying to change a URL after I have created it in Java and I cannot

Tags: java

I have created a program which reads a file from an online source. However, that source is not the same every time, so I have created some variables to change it according to user input. I have also thought about the chance that someone might not enter a valid URL address, so I have created a While statement that will be able to change it after the first wrong link is entered. However, after the while statement runs, and the URL is validated, I cannot access the file because of how I've written the rest of the code.

I am aware this is probably not the best option, but I am quite new to programming and this is all I could come up with. I would appreciate any and all suggestions, in any part of the code.
There is more, but that is irrelevant to the specific question.

Here is the excerpt of the code in question:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Project
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {

    //This creates the variable that changes the location and month of the chosen place 
    String place;
    String year;
    String month;
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the desired place (English characters, no capital letters. Example kalavryta");
    place = scn.next(); 
    System.out.println("Enter the desired month. Example: 06");
    month = scn.next();
    System.out.println("Enter the desired year:");
    year = scn.next();

    //Here, the above variables are combined to create the URL with the file. Then, we check if the file exists. 
    //And then the .txt file that resides in that URL with the data is imported from meteo's database
    URL oracle = new URL("https://meteosearch.meteo.gr/data/" + place + "/" + year + "-" + month + ".txt");
    HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) oracle.openConnection();

    int responseCode = huc.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Response code: " + responseCode);
    boolean correct = false;

    if(responseCode == 220) correct = true;
    while(responseCode == 404) 
    {
        System.out.println("The location/ period combination you are trying to view does not have any data. Try another location or a different period.");

        System.out.println("Enter another place (English characters, no capital letters. Ex. kalavryta)");
        place = scn.next(); 
        System.out.println("Enter the desired month. Example: 06");
        month = scn.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the desired year:");
        year = scn.next();

        URL attempt2 = new URL("https://meteosearch.meteo.gr/data/" + place + "/" + year + "-" + month + ".txt");
        huc = (HttpURLConnection) attempt2.openConnection();
        responseCode = huc.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Response code: " + responseCode);
    }
    if(correct)
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));  //reads the file
    }
    if(!correct)
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(attempt2.openStream()));
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you assign it to the first variable (oracle) instead of attempt2 you should be fine (however the answers with restructuring into a helper method are much nicer)

Answer (score 2):

How about splitting your code into several methods, then you can easily put them into a loop:

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{

    static Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);

    enum Status {SUCCESS, NOTFOUND, OTHER}

    static Status readFromUrl(String url) throws Exception
    {
        //Here, the above variables are combined to create the URL with the file. Then, we check if the file exists.
        //And then the .txt file that resides in that URL with the data is imported from meteo's database
        URL oracle = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) oracle.openConnection();

        int responseCode = huc.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Response code: " + responseCode);

        if(responseCode>=200 && responseCode<=299)
        {
            // TODO Read the file
            return Status.SUCCESS;
        }
        else if(responseCode>=400 && responseCode<=499)
        {
            return Status.NOTFOUND;
        }
        else
        {
            return Status.OTHER;
        }
    }

    static String promptForUrl()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a place (English characters, no capital letters. Ex. kalavryta)");
        String place = scn.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the desired month. Example: 06");
        String month = scn.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the desired year:");
        String year = scn.next();
        return "https://meteosearch.meteo.gr/data/" + place + "/" + year + "-" + month + ".txt";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String url;
        Status status;
        do
        {
            url = promptForUrl();
            status=readFromUrl(url);

            if (status==Status.NOTFOUND)
            {
                System.out.println("The location/ period combination you are trying to view does not have any data. Try another location or a different period.");
            }
        }
        while (status==Status.NOTFOUND);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should split your code into two methods, one for entering the values and one for retrieving the data. The reusing the methods is much easier in case of a bad URL:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // This creates the variable that changes the location and month of the chosen place
    String place;
    String year;
    String month;
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter the desired place (English characters, no capital letters. Example kalavryta");
        place = scn.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the desired month. Example: 06");
        month = scn.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the desired year:");
        year = scn.next();
        try {
            getData(place, year, month);
            break; // exit the while loop
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error retrieving data: " + e);
            System.out.println("The location/ period combination you are trying to view does not have any data. "
                    + "Try another location or a different period.");
        }

    }
}

public static void getData(String place, String year, String month) throws IOException {

    // Here, the above variables are combined to create the URL with the file. Then, we check if the file exists.
    // And then the .txt file that resides in that URL with the data is imported from meteo's database
    URL oracle = new URL("https://meteosearch.meteo.gr/data/" + place + "/" + year + "-" + month + ".txt");
    HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) oracle.openConnection();

    int responseCode = huc.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Response code: " + responseCode);
    if (responseCode != 220) {
        throw new IOException("received a HTTP " + responseCode);
    }
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(huc.getInputStream()))) {
        // ... read the text data
    }
}
```